# I'm trying to make a password creator

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a password creator to create a password for a assessment and one of the things that's needed is if the password doesn't have at least 2 numbers in it will print a error asking for a password with at least two numbers. I do not know how to do this and I was just wondering if you could give me a little hint on how I could do this in code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your title says you want a password creator, but the question says you want to validate a password. Which one is it? Also, what have you tried so far and what problem are you having? A good first step may be to come up with a [function signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: You need to actually try something first before posting something here. Look up http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html ...

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
import re

passw = 'hell1owo2rld'
if re.match('.*[0-9].*[0-9].*', passw):
    print 'Password is ok'
else
    print 'Please use at least two numbers'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using string methods, a list comprehension, and `len`:

```
if len([x for x in your_password_variable if x.isdigit()]) >= 2:
    print "OK"
else:
    print "You need at least 2 numbers"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is indeed to create a new password, I explain how to do it, but no code:

Use the `random.SystemRandom()` if you want secure passwords.

First create N characters from the set of allowed characters, where N is the length of your password. Then check if there are at least 2 digits. If there are less than 2 digits characters then remove 1 or 2 non-digit characters and add random digits, so that there are at least those 2 digits. Finally use the `shuffle()` to permute your password. That way your password has maximum entropy possible.